# OnActionExecuting ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, webapi

I am trying to get value of the parameter from action method, instead of underlined value, should not there be key?(x.key) in order to get the argument name?

```
var param = context.ActionArguments
  .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value.ToString().Contains("DTO")).Value;

[HttpPost]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidationFilterAttribute))]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCompany([FromBody] CompanyForCreationDTO company)
```

Comment: yes, there is a x.Key. Don't know if it matters but which code versions are you using (.net version)

Comment: I am currently using 3.1 long term support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way, It will bring the parameter value of a controller which has been passed.

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                var parameters = descriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters();

                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    var argument = context.ActionArguments[parameter.Name];
                }
            }
            
        }
```

***Output:***

[image]

You can get more info in [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: I have changed the code to this version, I think its better. Thank you soooo much

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: No problem at all, glad to assist this.